# How to determine '/' or '\' when constructing domain+username string

Tags: java

I can get the domain and username from NTSystem ok and have produced a "domain\username" string but have noticed that on my laptop and other machines the slash is '\' but on our virtual machines the slash is '/'. Is there any way to determine which way round the slash is?

I am then trying to create a user in SQL server as a Windows user. SQL server doesn't recognize the user if the slash is the wrong way round for the machine setup.

All machines are Windows

Comment: `File.separator`?

Comment: @dehasi the question is not about the filesystem though.

Comment: You can provide the domain in parameter instead of putting it in the username. `jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://host:port;databaseName=dbname;domain=domainName` This should work, can't test it unfortunalty.

Comment: I am connecting to SQL server successfully as the logged on user but it is when I try to create a different user that I get an error.

Answer (score 0):

File.separator will give you a System dependent String "\" for windows or "/" for unix/linux. But you also can just use "/" as Windows will understand it and convert it properly by itself

Comment: For the file system but is it the same for domain URI ?

Comment: for uri you can always use '/'

Comment: So based on what you said, you can use "/" to connect to SQL server using the windows domain. But the question stands the opposite.

Comment: @Axel, based on my experience, yes for URI you always can use "/", and that's what I am saying. There are always some configurations issues so the user may be experiencing some not standard situation. In this case he may rely on File.separator

Comment: So, not every URI use `/` or you would not use `File.separator` that only depends on the OS running the JVM. Note that the question mention that "_All machines are Windows_", so this should always be using the same separator but here, based on the problem asked, it seems to use one or the other.